# How to add leading zeros

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to know how can I get the leading zero's here. I already tried `%H` AND `%h` but still not working.Any help would be appreciable.Thank you

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE eventDate = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d-%m-%Y') AND time BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR),'%H:%i') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE),'%H:%i')
```

**UPDATE:**
 It just doesn't work between 00:00 and 02:00.. Do someone has any ideia why it's happening??

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.  Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: The thing is.. When it's 00:00 until 09:59 am, the data doesn't show.. its just works between 10:00 to 23:59 :/ @GordonLinoff

Comment: stills not working :( @KrisRoofe

Comment: The format `%H:%i` will include leading zeros.  If your query does not return expected results, it's probably something to do with your table schema and/or data.  Update your question with the schema and row data for the `events` table.

Comment: at the moment the row `time` is: 00:06 and server date time is: 00:06 (I changed to test) and is not working @user2045006

Comment: maybe the problem is because the INTERVAL.. idk... :( any ideias?

Comment: Have you check your data? I have test this SQL, and did return with leading zeros: `select now(), date_format(NOW(), '%d-%m-%Y'), DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR),'%H:%i'), DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE),'%H:%i'), DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE),'%H:%i')`

Comment: Did you test between 00:00 and 02:00? create a column with time with the format `00:00` and tell me please @Alex

Comment: I can't change the server time, but I have declare the variable and test, result as here: http://rextester.com/DXZMD34841

Comment: I have no ideias how to fix it :( do you have teamviewer to help me? :( @Alex

Comment: Can u help me @Barmar ? :(

Comment: But the current time is correct.. :/ @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said your problem only exists when time between `00:00` and `02:00`, it caused by this code:

> DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR),'%H:%i')

Let's break your code into few parts:

```
select date_format(curdate(), '%d-%m-%Y') as date_only, 
       DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR),'%H:%i') as min2h,
       DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE),'%H:%i') as add10m

# assume now = 2016/10/28 01:00
# the date_only will return 2016/10/28
# the min2h will return 23:00
# the add10m will return 01:10
```

back to your query, you will have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE eventDate = '20161028' AND time BETWEEN '23:00' AND '01:10'
```

That's why you can't get the result which the statement is not correct.  You should convert your `eventDate` and `time` to `datetime` first, so that you can compare the `datetime` correctly when *minus 2 hours is yesterday* or *add 10 minutes is tomorrow*

```
select * from events 
where str_to_date(concat(`eventDate`, " ", `time`), '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i') # convert o datetime, depends on your format
between date_sub(@report_date, interval 2 hour)
and date_add(@report_date, interval 10 minute)
```

[Fiddle](http://rextester.com/VADOS13155)

Comment: I already changed the `eventDate` and `time` to `datetime` and stills the same :/ now I dont even get if is after 02:00 or before 00:00 :/ Do you have teamviewer? I can give you my id and pass to help me :(

Comment: @RodrigoPacheco What you mean still the same? What's datatype of your `eventDate` and `time`, and any sample data?  BTW, it's not appropriate to use teamviewer to solve any question.

Comment: It's bot to solve, it's juts to help me :/ the format in both of them is `2016-10-28 03:22:00`

Comment: @RodrigoPacheco what you mean both of them? I have updated the SQL, which I have use the `concat_ws` in wrong way

Comment: the `eventDate` and `time` is `2016-10-28 03:22:00` now

Comment: @RodrigoPacheco both are the same value and data type is string or datetime?

Comment: datetime.. And btw, now I got it: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '", `time`), '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i')b' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in`

Comment: If you have the datetime field, you don't need to convert that.  Just compare it as `eventDate between date_sub(...) and date_add(...)`, assume eventDate and time is the same

Comment: But I don't want to keep `datetime` in `eventDate` and `time` , can I put in VARCHAR?

Comment: please check the fiddle, let me know if you have different table structure or data

Comment: Where u have `@report_date` should I put now()? Or I leave it like that?

Comment: You should replace with `now()`, I use that because I can't change the server time :D

Comment: and about `str_to_date` and `concat` ?

Comment: You said you want to keep `eventDate` and `time` as `varchar`, so you need to use `str_to_date` to convert `varchar` to `datetime`, and use `concat` to concatenate `eventDate` and `varchar` together.

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '", 'time'), '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i')b' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in` I'm getting this error

Comment: the `time` should be quoted by ` but not **'**, which **`** is escaped character, **'** means is for string. Moreover, maybe you can post your whole SQL, otherwise we can tell the exact problem is

Comment: You're the GOD ! OMG u solved my problem ! I'll put the answer as correct, but can you edit your answer with a short brief describing why it wasn't working? Because it's blowing my mind, because I was adding and substracting the time, should work before..

Comment: Glad you have solved it.  And which part you want me to explain more?

Comment: One more thing.. If I have an event today at 23:50 ... After 10 minutes will be tommorow, so it will disappear and will not be there during 2 hours how I want.. How can I fix it? **EDIT:** ohhh, forget it, I already tested it and worked.. sorry ! THANK YOU ONE MORE TIME !!

Comment: What you mean? It should be valid with that SQL: '2016/10/28 23:50' between '2016/10/28 23:00' and '2016/10/29 01:10'